# How to show shamsi date in django?

Tags: django, persian-calendar

I'm trying to make django's default 'DateTimeField' to show Shamsi (Persian) calendar, but I have no idea of how to do it. Is there any way to make this type of field use Shamsi completely or use it as it is and just converting to Shamsi when showing on the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and solved it by just adding a textfield for shamsi date and converting the date manually each time. It't not the best way but it gets the job done!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late but you can use [jalai-date](https://pypi.org/project/django_jalali/)